# Managing rental charges for movies

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

The condition for refactoring is:

> Define 2 new rules with respect to rental charges that are applicable and with the ability to add new categories of movies.
>
> Ex: Rental amount for children's movie for more than 2 days should be 100 from 3rd day onwards.

I have 3 classes (`Children`, `Movie` and `Rental`). I need suggestions on code smell and refactoring it.

**Customer.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList rentals = new ArrayList();

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addRental(Rental arg) {
        rentals.add(arg);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

     public String statement() { 
    
        double totalAmount = 0;
        int frequentRenterPoints = 0;
        
        String returnVal = "Rental record for : " + this.getName() + ".....\n";
        
        Iterator iter = rentals.iterator();
        
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            double thisAmount = 0;
            Rental each = (Rental) iter.next();
            //determine amounts for each line
            switch (each.getMovie().getPriceCode()) {
                case Movie.REGULAR: thisAmount += 100;
                if (each.getDaysRented() > 2)
                    thisAmount += (each.getDaysRented() - 2) * 75; 
                break;
                
                case Movie.NEW_RELEASE:
                thisAmount += each.getDaysRented() * 150; 
                break;
                
                case Movie.CHILDREN:
                thisAmount += 75;
                if (each.getDaysRented() > 3)
                thisAmount += (each.getDaysRented() - 3) * 75; 
                break;
            }
            
            
            // add frequent renter points
            frequentRenterPoints ++;
            // add bonus for a two day new release rental
            if ((each.getMovie().getPriceCode() == Movie.NEW_RELEASE) && each.getDaysRented() > 1) 
                frequentRenterPoints ++;
            
            //show figures for this rental
            returnVal += "\t" + each.getMovie().getTitle() + ": " + thisAmount + "\n";
            totalAmount += thisAmount;

        }
        
        //print footer
        returnVal += "Amount owed is: " + totalAmount + "\n";
        returnVal += "You have earned " + frequentRenterPoints + " frequent renter points";

        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

**Movie.java**

```
public class Movie {
    
    public static final int CHILDREN = 2;
    public static final int REGULAR = 0;
    public static final int NEW_RELEASE = 1;
    
    private String title;
    private int priceCode;

    public Movie(String title, int priceCode) {
        this.title = title;
        this.priceCode = priceCode;
    }

    public int getPriceCode() {
        return priceCode;
    }

    public void setPriceCode(int arg) {
        priceCode = arg;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

**Rental.java**

```
class Rental {
    
    private Movie movie;
    private int daysRented;

    public Rental(Movie movie, int daysRented) {
        this.movie = movie;
        this.daysRented = daysRented;
    }

    public int getDaysRented() {
        return daysRented;
    }

    public Movie getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried making a class movie as an Abstract class and added 2 abstract methods to calculate fare and points and then created concrete classes of movies (children, new) by extending the movie class. can this remove all the code smells ?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed about your code, is that you don't clearly have a movie category. I did find these methods on `Movie` after a while

```
public int getPriceCode() {
    return priceCode;
}

public void setPriceCode(int arg) {
    priceCode = arg;
}
```

I believe the getter would better be renamed to `getCategory()`. I would also completely remove the setter. It's really unlikely for a movie to change categories, so it should only be set during construction.

It might also be worth writing a specific class `Category` to list all possible categories. An enum would be the most natural here, but this might be awkward with the requirement:

> with the ability to add new categories of movies.

If it's no problem to recompile the code with a new movie (as I expect is the case in this example program) then the enum is still the better choice here.

```
public enum Category {
    CHILDREN, REGULAR, NEW_RELEASE;
}
```

This also changes the Movie class to this:

```
public class Movie {
    private final String title;
    private final Category category;

    public Movie(String title, Category category) {
        this.title = title;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Notice that I also added `final` to the fields to make it clear that a movie instance is immutable. Immutability is nice to have.

---

The other thing I didn't expect in your code is that the `Customer` class is responsible for calculating the "statement".

If I wanted to add a new category to the code, I wouldn't expect that I need to change the Customer class as well.

There are 2 major ways to solve this smell. Either put the "statement" calculations into a specialised class. Or add category specific calculations to that category.

Let's take a look into the second option since this might not be trivial if you're not used to working with enums in java.

I would implement it like this:

```
public enum Category {
    CHILDREN {
        @Override
        public int calculateRent(int daysRented) {
            int result = 75;
            if (daysRented > 3)
                result += (daysRented - 3) * 75;
            return result;
        }
    }, REGULAR {
        @Override
        public int calculateRent(int daysRented) {
            int result = 100;
            if (daysRented > 2)
                result += (daysRented - 2) * 75;
            return result;
        }
    }, NEW_RELEASE {
        @Override
        public int calculateRent(int daysRented) {
            return daysRented*150;
        }
    };

    public abstract int calculateRent(int daysRented);
}
```

This way, we can simplify the `statement()` in `Customer` to:

```
public String statement() {
    double totalAmount = 0;
    int frequentRenterPoints = 0;

    String returnVal = "Rental record for : " + this.getName() + ".....\n";

    for(Rental rental : rentals){
        double thisAmount = rental.getMovie().getCategory().calculateRent(rental.getDaysRented());

        frequentRenterPoints ++;
        if ((rental.getMovie().getCategory() == Category.NEW_RELEASE) && rental.getDaysRented() > 1) {
            frequentRenterPoints ++;
        }

        returnVal += "\t" + rental.getMovie().getTitle() + ": " + thisAmount + "\n";
        totalAmount += thisAmount;

    }

    returnVal += "Amount owed is: " + totalAmount + "\n";
    returnVal += "You have earned " + frequentRenterPoints + " frequent renter points";

    return returnVal;
}
```

With this change, adding a new Category only changes a single class (the enum).

Some other things to point out that I improved in this method:

**foreach**

Since java 5 I believe, there's a specialised way to loop over all itmes in a collection. The syntax here is `for(Rental rental : rentals)` which reads as "for each rental in rentals".

**meaningful names**

I renamed your `each` variable to `rental`. If you read this later on in the method it's more clear that it's the rental you're talking about.

**comments are clutter**

Comments are rarely useful. A comment should never be added to say what some line of code does. The only exception being a javadoc for methods (because you usually look at the javadoc from outside the class if you're interested in what that method does that it's name doesn't already tell you).

If you really need a comment to be able to understand some line(s) of code, you should either rename variables/methods in that line or extract a method with a name that clearly says what happens.

**Always put {}**

You should put curly brackets after each for/if/else/...
This is to prevent really difficult to debug mistakes like this:

```
if ((each.getMovie().getPriceCode() == Movie.NEW_RELEASE) && each.getDaysRented() > 1)
            System.out.println("Added bonus frequenterpoints");
            frequentRenterPoints ++;
```

All I did was add a print to see if anyone had bonus points added. But this innocent looking change cause EVERYONE to get a bonus point independent of the `if` check.

Most IDE's can be configured to automatically add the braces for you.

---

edit: making rentalpoints dependant on category as well.

Since the ammount of rental points depends on the category too, let's add another method in that enum. Since it only changes for a new release, I would add a default implementation that returns `1` and override this in the `NEW_RELEASE`. The new `Category` enum now looks like this:

```
public enum Category {
    CHILDREN {
        @Override
        public int calculateRent(int daysRented) {
            int result = 75;
            if (daysRented > 3)
                result += (daysRented - 3) * 75;
            return result;
        }
    }, REGULAR {
        @Override
        public int calculateRent(int daysRented) {
            int result = 100;
            if (daysRented > 2)
                result += (daysRented - 2) * 75;
            return result;
        }
    }, NEW_RELEASE {
        @Override
        public int calculateRent(int daysRented) {
            return daysRented*150;
        }

        @Override
        public int calculateFrequentRenterPoints(int daysRented) {
            if(daysRented > 1){
                return 2;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    };

    public abstract int calculateRent(int daysRented);
    public int calculateFrequentRenterPoints(int daysRented){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Now there's one more principle that I too have to get used to. It's the **tell, don't ask**. This is violated inside the `statement` method.

What we're doing is *asking* a rental for it's movie, then *asking* the movie for it's category and then once more *asking* the rental for the number of days rented. And then do the same asking for the frequent renter points.

This is too much asking. It would make more sense to just *tell* rental to calculate the price and then return the result. This way we only ask for one thing.

If we move those 2 methods to the `Rental` class istead, then our `statement` method will turn to this:

```
public String statement() {
    double totalAmount = 0;
    int frequentRenterPoints = 0;

    String returnVal = "Rental record for : " + this.getName() + ".....\n";

    for(Rental rental : rentals){
        frequentRenterPoints += rental.calculateFrequentMoviePoints();

        double thisAmount = rental.calculateRent();
        returnVal += "\t" + rental.getMovie().getTitle() + ": " + thisAmount + "\n";
        totalAmount += thisAmount;
    }

    returnVal += "Amount owed is: " + totalAmount + "\n";
    returnVal += "You have earned " + frequentRenterPoints + " frequent renter points";

    return returnVal;
}
```

For completeness sake here's the new Rental class as well:

```
public class Rental {
    private Movie movie;
    private int daysRented;

    public Rental(Movie movie, int daysRented) {
        this.movie = movie;
        this.daysRented = daysRented;
    }

    public int getDaysRented() {
        return daysRented;
    }

    public Movie getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }

    public int calculateRent() {
        return movie.getCategory().calculateRent(daysRented);
    }

    public int calculateFrequentMoviePoints() {
        return movie.getCategory().calculateFrequentRenterPoints(daysRented);
    }
}
```

This actually makes a lot more sense. A `Customer` only knows that it can ask a rental for the price and points, it doesn't need to know how those are calculated.

A `Rental` needs to know who to ask for the actual price or points, and has the information needed to calculate those (in this case, the number of days rented).

A `Category` contains category - specific calculations. Adding a new category means only implementing a new field in the enum. No other classes need to be changed.

---

Your idea of putting it into subclasses of movie (eliminating the Category class altogether) would work too. It's even better for the `Rental` class since it doesn't need to know that there exist such a thing as different categories of movies.

The only reason I would not go for this solution is the reason to change a Movie class. If your name is just an identifier for the movie, and no other info about the movie is stored in that class than I would completely agree with this being a good solution. Except that I would change the name to something else. (If only I could find a decent name for that specific concept ... naming things is *hard*). Let's give it the not so awesome name `RentableMovie` for now.

That would mean a Customer has a bunch of `Rentals`.
Each of those rentals has a number of days and a `RentableMovie`.
That `RentableMovie` contains specific ways of calculating the price and points. It only contains 1 identifier for the movie. Or we could introduce a new `MovieInformation` class so that the `RentableMovie` can point to all information about the movie, without knowing what exactly is in it.

This would work as well :)
So you can choose what feels best to you.

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution. But I would like to put attention that the frequentRenterPoints are still in customer class and is tightly coupled with it. If we need to introduce renter point for each new movie , it will be difficult to maintain and change the renter calculation logic.** I am not clear that the if the customer class is doing calculation for renterPoints and rent, is it following SIngleResponsibilityPrinciple ?.** I will post my solution also which is somewhat similar to yours. Please suggest changes in that or some best approach.

Comment: @Imus: Enums shouldn't provide business logic. It's an _enumerated type_, it represents a _state_ or a _constant_ value. Adding logic to it does violate the single responsibility pattern imo. It will backfire, when the calculation needs other parameters, for instance "regular customer" or "special offer 10% off rent" or "special offer rent two, rent one for free". I would have used a dedicated "RentCalculationService" or something similar.

Comment: @Imus: so going with the solution of the subclasses that I have posted and incorporating your suggestion also at the same time, I didn't understand **RentableMovie(Movie renmed) only contains 1 identifier for the movie. Or we could introduce a new MovieInformation class so that the RentableMovie can point to all information about the movie, without knowing what exactly is in it.** Can you please make it more clear. And after this will there be any code smell left in Customer class if I go with the Subclass solution.

Comment: The subclass itself will work. But think about the major responsibility of those classes. Are they responsible for calculating the rental price and frequent renter points? Or are they responsible for providing detailed information about the movie? If your answer is both, then that's a code smell. In that subclass solution it should be responsible only for the calculations. And at best have a "pointer" to another class that can tell everything about the movie. That way it's not responsible for the details, but it can point you to someone else who does have those details.

Answer (score 1):

> `private ArrayList rentals = new ArrayList();`

The list contains `Rental` objects so you should make it generic. No more cast needed!

`private List<Rental> rentals = new ArrayList<>();`

ps: I changed the type from `ArrayList` (implementation) to `List` (interface) for maintainability purpose, see [Interface-based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming).